# Enabling Accessibility service: Why does it degrade security?

Tags: security, lock-screens, encryption, permissions

Device : Mi A1, 7.1.2 Stock Google

Enabling Accessibility Service for apps impacts encryption  security as you can see:

[image]

Expanded text

[image]

**Why is this?**

I am all the more curious in case of PIN  : my understanding is that, encryption password is generated from a combination of user lock screen PIN and encryption algorithm. This is salted, and stored in root location, and used to generate the actual password to encrypt /decrypt. So using a longer PIN length ([to maximum of 16 digits](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154588/131553) 
)  is **pointless** if you have enabled Accessibility Service for any app?? Confused

Related to this

**Should apps seeking Accessibility Service be considered an anti security feature?**

Comment: Through Accessibility service you can get to see what is visible on the Window, where and when the screen was tapped and  the size of the item (you can pretty much map the data to get the PIN).

Comment: @Firelord: thanks. Care to elaborate in the form of a detailed answer please? Also wonder about the last question - it doesn't appear to be considered so

Comment: @Firelord: Was going thru permissions required by those apps . **MacroDroid**- *Auto Press Back button, Detect Vol changes, Auto expand/ collapse status bar. Launch UI Dailogs Detect current active app*-:**Notification History**- *Record USSD class 0 msgs dialogs app toasts and notifications on Status bar*; **QuickAppLock Pro** to *monitor which app has been opened*. Couldn't think how above fit into your view  so disabled all and enabled only one at a time. **Conclusion???**- it doesn't matter what the permission is used for - it gets triggered merely by giving permission to any app