# Make my screen unlock pin longer than 31 digits

Tags: root-access, security, lock-screens, android-10, huawei-p20

My question is pretty self-explaining. Currently I have a PIN number of maximum possible digits (31) that my Android 10 supports (phone is Huawei P20 Pro). Is there a way to make it longer than that? Any third party software, by rooting the phone or something similar?

Comment: Related [Why, and how to increase 16-character lockscreen password limit?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154588/why-and-how-to-increase-16-character-lockscreen-password-limit)